# Pass closest value via ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a table created using a while loop thats displays a list of items so that the user can select an item to delete which is done via ajax.

I would like to use `JQuery's` closest attribute but I can't work out the correct syntax.  The output I get from this is `Object Object`

The table

```
<form id="del_opinion">
  <table id="asked_list">
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    <tr>
       <td>
         <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
       </td>
     <td>
        <input type="button" name="del_question" value="" class="trash_btn">
            <input type="hidden" class="id_question" name="question_id" value="<? echo $row['questionID']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" class="id_user" name="user" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"  >      
     </td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
  </table>
</form>
```

The ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.trash_btn').click(function(){
    var question = $(this).closest('.id_question');
    var user = $(this).closest('id_user');  
$.ajax({
        url: 'opinion_del.php',
        type:'POST',
        data: 'question='+ question +'&user='+user,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
                $('#responses_table').html(response);
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert(thrownError);
    } // End of success function of ajax form
        }); // End of ajax call    

    });
});
</script>
```

The php have done for testing

```
$question_id = $_POST['question'];
$id = $_POST['user'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM adviceQuestion WHERE questionID = '$question_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
if($result){
    $output = $question_id;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

If I type a literal value to `$output` it works fine and if I type a literal value in either of the `jquery vars` they work correctly too so I'm convinced it is something to do with the closest syntax

I have also tried adding a class to the table row called `details` and using

```
var question = $(event.target).closest('.details').find('.id_question');
```

If I alert question it says `[object Object]`

Comment: Try to remove dataTYpe: 'Json'

Because:
echo json_encode($output); you output and id so it is string or try to output array...
I had something similar cant remember But you code looks fine to me...

Comment: it still the same thing, just says [object Object]

Comment: if I type a literal value into 'var user' that value is passed back correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = $(this).closest('id_user');
```

Change to this

```
var user = $(this).closest('.id_user');
```

You didnt specified a c lass "." dot ))) Maybe will help

Comment: well spotted but same problem

Answer (score 0):

OK, sussed it...

Changed this

```
var question = $(this).closest('.id_question');
var user = $(this).closest('id_user');
```

to

```
var question = $(this).next('.id_question').val();
var user = $(this).next('.id_user').val();
```